# My AMP html is valid but not appearing as AMP in facebook post or google search results

Tags: amp-html

This is my [Non AMP site with amphtml link available](http://biz-address.co.uk), As we know that Facebook is currently showing amp pages if it's availble, But when I posted the above url it doesn't link it to my amp page.

I also tried g.co/ampdemo/ it doesn't show the amp version. 
Am I missing anything here ?

Note: Page passes amp validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was :
**AMP error: Missing supported structured data element**

It is no where mentioned that you also should have to add structured data element in the AMP html page.

But If you don't have Structured data element Google or Facebook invalidates the amp html page.

But so is no the case with AMP Validators my page passed all amp validators. [image]

Comment: Hi,  that is mentioned in [ampproject.org](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery), in the section called "Use Schema.org for most search engines"

Comment: Yes, the Structured Data element is a Google-specific requirement for the AMP Carousel, it is not required for AMP itself. Your page can still load in the cache and Google will still show the AMP icon next to normal search results.

Comment: Correct @Gregable This is the first time I was implementing this so I was confused.